# Matlab: "Matrix Exceeds Dimensions Error" in While Loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

My tutor and I were solving problem simulating the war card game. The only variation in the rules is that two cards with same value are both discarded.

My tutor and I came up with a solution

```
deck1 = randi(13,1,26);
    deck2 = randi(13,1,26);

    winner1 = 0;
    winner2 = 0;
    n = 1;

    while (length(deck1) ~= 0 || length(deck1) ~= 0)
        n = length(deck1);
        m = length(deck2);
        if deck1(1) == deck2(1)
            deck1(1) = [];
            deck2(1) = [];
        elseif deck1(1) < deck2(1) 
            winner2 = winner2 + 1;
            deck2(m+1) = deck2(1);
            deck1(1) = [];
            deck2(1) = [];
        else 
            deck1(27) = deck1(1);
            deck1(n+1) = deck2(1);
            deck1(1) = [];
            deck2(1) = [];
            winner1 = winner1 + 1;
        end
    end

    if winner1 > winner2
        k = 1;
    elseif winner1 == winner2
        k = 0;
    else k = 2;
    end
    disp(k)
```

The loop works for k=2 and k=0 but not for k=1. It return the following

```
 Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in TutorVersionWarCardGame (line 16)
    if deck1(1) == deck2(1)
```

How should I edit the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare `deck1` 2 times in the while loop as below

```
while (length(deck1) ~= 0 || length(deck1) ~= 0)
```

I think it should be

```
while (length(deck1) ~= 0 || length(deck2) ~= 0)
```

Edit:

I added [try catch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) to check the `if` conditions inside the `while` loop. I found matrix keep decrease until its size reaches to 0, therefore, I replace the `||` with `&&` while `(length(deck1) ~= 0 && length(deck2) ~= 0)` but the result now always k=2.

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the error message “index exceeds matrix dimensions” along with “error in line 16: if deck1(1)==deck2(1)”

Comment: I see. I added [try catch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) to check the  `if ` conditions inside the  `while ` loop. I found matrix keep decrease until its size reaches to 0, therefore, I replace the || with &&  `while (length(deck1) ~= 0 && length(deck2) ~= 0)` but the result now always k=2.

Comment: I figured it out a few days ago. Thank you for responding. I’m accepting your answer though you should add you comment.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
deck1 = randi(13,1,26);
deck2 = randi(13,1,26);

winner1 = 0;
winner2 = 0;
n = 1;

while (~isempty(deck1) && ~isempty(deck2))
    n = length(deck1);
    m = length(deck2);

    if deck1(1) == deck2(1)
        deck1(1) = [];
        deck2(1) = [];
    elseif deck1(1) < deck2(1) 
        winner2 = winner2 + 1;
        deck2(m+1) = deck2(1);
        deck1(1) = [];
        deck2(1) = [];
    else 
        deck1(27) = deck1(1);
        deck1(n+1) = deck2(1);
        deck1(1) = [];
        deck2(1) = [];
        winner1 = winner1 + 1;
    end
end

if winner1 > winner2
    k = 1;
elseif winner1 == winner2
    k = 0;
else
    k = 2;
end

disp(k);
```

Comment: How come `~isempty(deck1) || ~isempty(deck2)` but `(length(deck1) ~= 0 || length(deck1) ~= 0)` doesn't?

Comment: Read about length in the official docs... you will understand why! :)

Comment: I checked your code again. It doesn't work for k=1 and k=0. There's something wrong with my MATLAB program.

Comment: Also, did you notice that in your while loop condition you were just checking the size of deck1? I edited my answer!

Comment: I changed the code but I get the error “index exceed matrix dimensions” and “error in line 16: if deck1(1)==deck2(1)”

Comment: Can we have at least an explanation about what you are trying to do with this code? We are just fixing errors without knowing what's the underlying purpose.

Anyway, with "(~isempty(deck1) && ~isempty(deck2))" I don't understand how that error on line 16 can happen.